# Time Frame for Travel Vaccine Shots

Tags: health

I am traveling to South Africa, Swaziland, and Zimbabwe.  The shots that I need are:

Typhoid, Yellow Fever, Hepatitis A and B, MMR, Flu Shot and Tetanus/Polio/Diphtheria (given as all-in-one vaccine)

Is there a specific order that these shots should be given in? How many months in advance should I start the shot regimen. I know that Hepatitis is a six month series.

Comment: You should go to a travel medicine clinic as early as practical before your trip and ask the professionals there these questions.

Comment: Related: [How far in advance to get travel vaccinations?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/6499/how-far-in-advance-to-get-travel-vaccinations)

Answer (score 4):

With the exception of the flu vaccine, all the other vaccinations offer long term protection, or are boosters to previously-received vaccinations. The hep A/B is three injections over six months: you have the first, the second one month later, and the third, five months after. The Tdap is is tetanus/pertussis/diptheria.

Other than scheduling the hepatitis series, you need to complete all inoculations no later than one week prior to departure, to allow the immunity to kick in. Ideally, it's recommended that you visit your doctor 4-6 weeks in advance to plan for the vaccines and medicines you'll need. The [Centers for Disease Control and Prevention Travelers' Health](http://wwwnc.cdc.gov/travel/) section has country-specific guidance.

Depending on your previous vaccination history, your physician may do a titer test, using a blood sample, to measure the presence and amount of antibodies in your system, to prove your levels of immunity.